# Rewrite code for Automapper v5.0 to v4.0

Tags: automapper, automapper-5

Automapper v4.0 was very straight forward to use within a method, can someone help rewrite this for v5.0 please (specifically the Mapper code):

```
    public IEnumerable<NotificationDto> GetNewNotifications()
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var notifications = _context.UserNotifications
            .Where(un => un.UserId == userId && !un.IsRead)
            .Select(un => un.Notification)
            .Include(n => n.Gig.Artist)
            .ToList();

        Mapper.CreateMap<ApplicationUser, UserDto>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Gig, GigDto>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Notification, NotificationDto>();

        return notifications.Select(Mapper.Map<Notification, NotificationDto>);
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
It seems that EF Core doesn't project what AutoMapper is mapping with:

```
return notifications.Select(Mapper.Map<Notification, NotificationDto>);
```

But I do get results in Postman with the following code:

```
        return notifications.Select(n => new NotificationDto()
        {
            DateTime = n.DateTime,
            Gig = new GigDto()
            {
                Artist = new UserDto()
                {
                    Id = n.Gig.Artist.Id,
                    Name = n.Gig.Artist.Name

                },
                DateTime = n.Gig.DateTime,
                Id = n.Gig.Id,
                IsCancelled = n.Gig.IsCancelled,
                Venue = n.Gig.Venue
            },
            OriginalVenue = n.OriginalVenue,
            OriginalDateTime = n.OriginalDateTime,
            Type = n.Type
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep using static instance - the only change is in mapper initialization:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<ApplicationUser, UserDto>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Gig, GigDto>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Notification, NotificationDto>();
});
```

Also you should run this code only once per AppDomain (somewhere on startup for example) and not every time you calling `GetNewNotifications`.

Comment: The mapper.map line doesn't seem to work. Looks like that needs to be rewritten too

Comment: Intellisense is complaining about this line return notifications.Select(Mapper.Map<Notification, NotificationDto>);

Comment: No overload for method 'Map' takes 0 arguments This is my code: return notifications.Select(Mapper.Map<Notification, NotificationDto>();

Comment: OK, you should pass `Map` as delegate to `Select` just like in your question: `notifications.Select(Mapper.Map<Notification, NotificationDto>);`. Pay attention to parenthesis

Comment: With this fix, I don't get any errors, but the result set doesn't return anything when I try in postman. I have uploaded my entire project, the NotificationsController is where I am having this issue. Also, what/where is the right place to create all the mappings? Thanks!

Comment: As for mappings - you can put them in `Startup`

Comment: There are notifications and they do show up when I use lambda expressions instead of AutoMapper. The notificications.select seems to be where the code doesn't return anything.

Comment: thanks for your input. I pulled into a variable and dug into the innerexception, the issue was that my Gig->GigDto mapping, had an internal Genre->GenreDto that I didnt map in the createmap. I just commented out that mapping since I don't need it.